# Access/generate java enums in/from javascript

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, enums

I have a some amount of Java code in my Project (more specificaly GWT)

I have decided to start using react for future features

Now the problem is that i need to access some Java enum in React to perform calls to server from Javascript (or whatever operation)

My questions are

A) Is there a way to access Java public enum values in Js ? If so ...how ?

B) Is there some tool to generate Javascript .js file from these enum and accesss it that way (maybe maven should know this ?)

Any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GWT 2.8.0 you can use the newly introduced annotations. There is a very good blog-post about it: [here](http://www.luigibifulco.it/blog/en/blog/gwt-2-8-0-jsinterop)